# Simplify Do While Loop Checking for Null Pointer

Tags: c++, list

I have a really basic problem that I can't figure out. I'm using chaining with hash tables to store nodes that collide with each other. I used a `do while` loop to print the first node at least once, and continue to print the chained nodes if they exist. However, in order to traverse the chained list, I need to change the address of the node for the next loop. Any way I try writing this, I find myself repeating code, which I was trying to avoid by using this loop. Please help

```
    do {
        cout << "Bid id: " << table.at(i)->bidId << " title: " << table.at(i)->title <<
        " fund: " << table.at(i)->fund << " amount: " << table.at(i)->amount << endl;
        if (table.at(i)->next!=nullptr){//check if first node has next node         
             table.at(i) = table.at(i)->next; //change address to the next pointer
        }// how do I avoid repeating my condition below?
    }
    while (table.at(i)->next!=nullptr);
```

Comment: Why not use `for` loop?

Comment: What is `table`? Present a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will replicate the functionality in your loop without duplicating the check against NULL.

```
while(true)
{
  cout << /* stuff */ endl;
  auto next = table.at(i)->next;
  if(next)
    table.at(i) = next;
  else
    break;
}
```

From the description though, are you sure you want to reassign the values inside your hash map while looping over them? I suspect that this code may suit your intent/needs better:

```
auto current = table.at(i);
while(current)
{
  cout << /* stuff */ endl;
  current = current->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself in a situation like this one, it's a good idea to question your premise. In this case, I am talking about your assumption that you need a `do while` loop.

If there is a chance that your data won't be there or that your container is empty, then a `do while` won't do the job because it will loop at least once.

Generally, for iterating through a collection of data you'll want to use a `for` or `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code correctly, you need a precondition loop and not a postcondition one, as you have right now. For example:

```
while (table.at(i)) {
    cout << "Bunch of stuff";
    table.at(i) = table.at(i)->next;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a small difference where after his loop `table.at(i)->next == NULL` but after your loop `table.at(i) == NULL`. That may or may not be important

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing:

```
for(auto node = table.at(i)->next;node!=nullptr;node=node->next)
  cout << "Bid id: " << node->bidId << " title: " << node->title;
```

Where you may need to replace `node = table.at(i)->next` with an appropriate way of getting a link to the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *C++11*'s *range based for loop* here. All you want to know is that `value->next` is not a `nullptr` before doing the assignment. Rest all is taken care by the **simple and modern** [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for(auto const& value: table) {
  if (value->next != nullptr) {
    value = value->next;
  }
}
```

Its even faster and safer this way

Comment: Depends on what `table` is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you mean this logic can fail if `table` is not an ordered container? or in case of certain type of containers?

Comment: The logic will fail unless `table` meets the requirements of a ranged-for loop (basically something with a `begin()` and an `end()`, where the resulting iterator can be incremented), and we have no idea whether `table` is one of those things.

Comment: yeah. I assumed that part. but the question does not say what `table` is. At least the question should clarify what type of container `table` is. This technique is a huge advantage though if `table` is a container supporting `begin()` and `end()`

Comment: While that's true, if the container in question had iterator support I doubt the OP would have arrived at such a convoluted iteration mechanism in the first place. We can at least tell that `table` isn't a standard container.

Answer (score 0):

If really you want to be able to get last element after the loop, you may do:

```
do {
    cout << "Bid id: " << table.at(i)->bidId
         << " title: " << table.at(i)->title
         << " fund: " << table.at(i)->fund
         << " amount: " << table.at(i)->amount << endl;
    if (table.at(i)->next == nullptr){
        break;
    }
    table.at(i) = table.at(i)->next;
} while (true);
// table.at(i) != nullptr && table.at(i)->next == nullptr
```